# How do open source/free software applications handle the client_secret in oauth? (Without a web server)

Tags: rest, oauth, oauth-2.0, open-source, google-oauth

I am making a tiny desktop application for my personal use. (Also for a few of my friends.) As part of this application, I am using OAuth 2 to access some of Google's APIs.

I want to eventually upload this to a server where potentially anyone could download it. So I can't just bundle the `client_secret` with the application.

So, I would like to know, how do open source applications that share there entire source code deal with this?

I could just require users to get their own `client_id` from google. But that's a bit of a cumbersome process, and I would ultimately end up writing a scraper to do it automatically, defeating the purpose, also it would be very brittle.

Alternatively, there is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616553/using-oauth-in-free-open-source-software) where the answer is to run your own server to act as a middle agent. However, because this is only a small app I'm doing for me and a few friends, I don't really want to manage a server just for this, and even if I did, it certainly would be fairly unstable.

In short, are there any solutions here that

- allow me to put my source code on the internet,
- don't require me to run my own server, and
- don't require my users to go get there own 'client_id' after they've already downloaded my desktop application, or require me to make a web scraper that does it for them?